# Необычная конструкция if в C/С++

Tags: c, c++

Сегодня увидел странную конструкцию if в коде:

```
#define ERROR_OK 0L

int foo();

// ...
if (ERROR_OK == foo() != ERROR_OK) 
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Так до конца и не понял, почему этот код работает и при каких значения функция выполняется. Понял, что если foo() вернет 0, то будет выполнена ветка внутри if. Помогите полностью разобраться.

Answer (score 20):

Ну, всё довольно просто. Давайте разбирать по кускам.

1) Выполняется сравнение `ERROR_OK == foo()`. Оно вернёт `true` или `false`, в зависимости от значения `ERROR_OK` и того, что вернёт функция.

2) Результат предыдущего вычисления (т.е. `true` или `fals`e) сравнивается с `ERROR_OK`. При этом то самое `true` или `false` приведётся к `int` `(true -> 1, false -> 0)`. Ну и обычное сравнение.

---

Соответственно, если считать, что `ERROR_OK = 0` (а в условии написано именно так), то первая часть условия эквивалентна `0 == foo()`, т.е. `!foo()`. Вторая часть условия эквивалентна `!foo() != 0`, т.е. `foo() == 0`, т.е. просто `!foo()`.
Значит, если `foo` вернёт `0`, то условие выполнится, а иначе — нет.

Comment: этот ответ должен быть принят

Answer (score 7):

Код эквивалентен !foo().
Синтаксис странный, но корректный.

Answer (score 6):

Значение условного выражения в секции if будет истинным всегда, когда функция foo() будет возвращать 0, независимо от того, чему равен ERROR_OK.

Comment: Насчёт независимости от ERROR_OK чересчур смело заявлено.
В конструкции обыгрывается факт, что значение операции == может быть 0 или 1. Если ERROR_OK == 1, то условие проверяет foo() != 1, при других значения ERROR_OK истинно всегда.

Answer (score 4):

Необычного и странного в конструкции ничего нет!
Чтобы не путаться, есть простое правило: выражение в скобках может возвращать либо true либо false. Если выражение даёт true, то выполняется то, что находится сразу после закрывающейся круглой скобки.
А само выражение в скобках разбирается согласно утверждённому приоритету операторов.

Answer (score -2):

Приоритет у (==) и (! =) одинаковый. Читается с лево на право. 0==х!=0 эквивалентно (0==х)!=0. Сначала происходит проверка на равенство затем полученное значение которое может быть равно 1 или 0(истина или ложь) сравнивается со значением 0.Такая конструкция при условии что все три операнда разные имеет смысл. В шапке темы это не так. Поэтому я называю это семантической ошибкой. Масло масленное. ERROR_OK в свою очередь не может быть ==1 потому что он задефинен с вполне определённым значением. #define ERROR_OK 0L. Тоесть ноль. Или не так?

```
//Что и требовалось доказать. 
#include<stdio.h>
#define ABC 0L

int main(void)
{
int z, x=5, y=100;
if (ABC==0!=ABC)// если 1!=0 true
    z=x*y;
else if(ABC==1!=ABC)// если 0!=0 false
    z=x+y;
else
    z=y-x;
    printf("z=%d", z);
    return 0;
}
//Вывод: z=500

/* Ок. Разворачиваем int foo()
Оба варианта условия if() дают
идентичный результат*/
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ABC 0L

int foo();

int main(void) 
{ 
int z,s,x, y=3;
for(x=-3;x<4;x++)
{
z=foo(x, y);
//if (ABC==foo(x, y)!=ABC)//Семантическая ошибка. 
if (ABC==foo(x, y))//Более здравая конструкция?
    printf("%2d %d %d\n", x, y, z); 
else
{
    s=y+10000;
    printf("%6d\n", s);
}
}
return 0; 
}

int foo(int p, int q)
{
int g=p/q;
return g;
}
Вывод:
  10003
 -2 3 0
 -1 3 0
  0 3 0
  1 3 0
  2 3 0
  10003
```

Comment: Мой минус за то, что вы не правильно прочитали листинг в шапке. прочитайте его ещё раз внимательно, и попытайтесь понять именно функцию `int foo() ;`.

Comment: Ок. Прототип функции возвращающий целое число. В себе может содержать всё что угодно. Кроме отсутствия функции main( ) ничего не смущает. Но если я правильно понял это фрагменты кода для демонстрации условия if (). Прошу пояснить если не затруднит что конкретно я упускаю. Это для меня важно. Или ссылку. Плизз.

Comment: исходя из листинга, можно сделать вывод, что функция `int foo()` будет возвращать `0`, либо любое другое число, которое будет интепретировано в условии `if` как истина(`true`). И по этому, когда функция вернёт `1`, то в условии будет сравниваться константа `0==1`, что в дальнейшем будет ложью и будет сравниваться `0! =0` и это будет ложь по этому будет выполняться тело `else`. А теперь берём `0`, первое условие `0==0` это истина, соответственно далее будет `1! =0`, что будет истина и исходя из этих сравнений, будет выполнена ветка `if`.

Comment: А теперь берём ваш листинг, у вас константа `ABC` всегда будет равняться`0`, и всегда будет выполняться `только` условие `if`. Остальное можно смело убрать.

Comment: /* Ок. Разворачиваем int foo()
    Оба варианта условия if() дают
    идентичный результат*/
    #include<stdio.h> 
    #define ABC 0L

    int foo();

    int main(void) 
    { 
    int z,s,x, y=3;
    for(x=-3;x<4;x++)
    {
    z=foo(x, y);
    //if (ABC==foo(x, y)!=ABC)//Семантическая 
    ошибка. 
    if (ABC==foo(x, y))//Более здравая конструкция?
        printf("%2d %d %d\n", x, y, z); 
    else
    {
    s=y+10000;
        printf("%6d\n", s);
    }
    }
    return 0; 
    }

    int foo(int p, int q)
    {
    int g=p/q;
    return g;
    }

Comment: @Генс, будьте более наблюдательны, для начала посмотрите на дату (и автора) вопроса. Обратите особое внимание на URL: `.../questions/339/...`. Потом можно посмотреть на даты ответов. Теперь включаете *свою логику* (и делаете правильные выводы)

Comment: В первом своём листинге я просто пытался показать опасность подобных усложнений в условиях if. Подобные выкрутасы обязательно будут приводить к неверным результатам вычислений при усложнении кода. При этом компилятор будет молчать. Получил минус. Ну ни чё. Спасибо что расшевелили.

Comment: У вас вывод ясно показывает,что в двух случаях у вас будет использована ветка `else` и это верные результаты, диапазон значений от `-2` до `2` будет действовать ветка `if`, так-как в этом диапазоне деление будет выдавать результат с дробью, а из-за того, что функция имеет тип `int`,  дробная часть усекаеться, по этому в остальных случаях ответ `0`, а в случае `-3` и `3`, ответ `10003`.

Comment: Поэтому я и выбрал целочисленное деление чтоб foo() возвращала и 0 и 1. Если увеличить диапазон for() то и остальные !0 пойдут в else. Ок.